# Remove extra space from footer of pdf file generated by cfhtmltopdf

Tags: pdf, coldfusion-11, html-to-pdf

I was working in generating pdf report from html content and I was trying to put footer html content in the pdf, but I'm unable to put it inside cfhtmltopdfitem tag, as div tag and class is not allowed inside it. So, I just kept it inside my html body, but I'm getting a huge space between the html footer and the actual pdf footer(as show in the image).

[image]

***Note: I feel for this one code sample is not required, if needed please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

I have put this question in ColdFusion forum, here is the reference: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2204100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your code it's hard to diagnose. If you're using `CFdocument`, set the `marginBottom="0"` property. EX:

```
<cfdocument
    scale="100" unit="in"
    format="pdf"
    name="temp"
    overwrite="yes"
    localUrl="no"
    fontEmbed="yes"
    marginBottom = "0"
    marginLeft = "0"
    marginRight = "0"
    marginTop = "0"
    pageWidth="7.5"
    pageHeight="10"
    orientation="landscape" >
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I was using cfhtmltopdf tag. I applied following setting to get it done.

<cfhtmltopdf saveAsName="my pdf" unit="in" marginbottom="0">

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice this was for CF11. Same property name though. So, I learned just as much from you!